# Can't install mono-gmcs package

Tags: linux, mono

I am trying to install the mono-gmcs package on my virtual machine running Kali Linux, but receive the output

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-gmcs : Depends: mono-mcs (= 3.12.1-0xamarin1) but 4.0.4.1-0xamarin1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am using the command `sudo apt-get install mono-gmcs` to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says, that mono-gmcs depends on mono-mcs (3.12.1-0xamarin1), which currently is installed via 4.0.4.1-0xamarin1. You have versions conflict. Downgrading xamarin will solve it `sudo apt-get install packagename=version`

Comment: What would be the easiest way to do this? Sorry I am new to linux and am needing this package for a class I am currently taking.

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get install mono-complete=3.12.1`

Comment: Now I get this error `E: Version '3.12.1' for 'mono-complete' was not found`

Comment: what returns `sudo apt-cache policy mono-complete`

Comment: Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.4.1-0xamarin1
  Version table:
     4.0.4.1-0xamarin1 0
        500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
     3.2.8+dfsg-10 0
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali/ kali-dev/main amd64 Packages
     2.10.8.1-8 0
        500 http://http.kali.org/ /kali/main amd64 Packages

Comment: Ok, so install mono-complete, it should provide you mono-gmcs.

Comment: Still not entirely sure if that worked. I am trying to install LOIC which appears to rely on this to install. Whenever I install LOIC and then try to open it, I cannot open it as the .exe hasn't been created.

I also get this error when it attempts to install

 error: /root/Desktop/loic/LOIC/IRC/IRC.csproj:
      /root/Desktop/loic/LOIC/IRC/IRC.csproj could not import
      "$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets"
error: /root/Desktop/loic/LOIC/IRC/IRC.csproj: /root/Desktop/loic/LOIC/IRC/IRC.csproj could not import "$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets"
/usr/bin/mono

Comment: There are so many versions of LOIC out in the wild, are you sure you are installing the correct version of mono, sounds like you need a 4.x version.

Comment: Mono 4 unified the compilers to a single so this package is no longer useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to choose Mono 4.* via mono-complete, say goodbye to many old packages such as this one. They are obsolete and you don't need them any more.

The compilers have been unified to a single mcs.

Comment: no more gmcs, dmcs
https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`sudo apt-get install mono-complete=*`

It brings the latest version.